# Testing Validity of Web Service Referenced in Layer File?

Tags: arcpy, .net, web-service, layer-file

My organization creates a number of layer files for our ArcMap users to access data from web services. Is there any way to use `arcpy.Describe` to get to the URL of the service referenced by the layer? My testing so far has only yielded paths back to the layer file itself, or a temp folder:

```
>>> d=arcpy.Describe(r'e:\geodata\ortho_imagery\naip_ca_historical.lyr')
>>> d.catalogPath
u'e:\\Geodata\\ortho_imagery\\naip_ca_historical.lyr'
>>> l=d.layer
>>> l.catalogPath
u'C:\\Users\\bjorn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\3\\NAIP_Historical/California_Historical'
```

I'd also be open to a .NET solution if necessary.

The ultimate goal is to develop a tool that will scan our shared drive for .lyr files, and if they refer to a web service, test its validity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some `arcpy.mapping.Layer` objects have a read only property `serviceProperties` that can be used to check this sort of thing. Two types of layers, ArcSDE and web services, support service properties. `serviceProperties` is a dictionary that has different key value pairs depending on the layer type. The dictionary of service properties for web services has a key `URL` that you can use to return the url of that service. However you first need to check if the layer supports `serviceProperties`, you can print out all of a layers service properties (granted it supports them) like this:

```
if layer.supports('SERVICEPROPERTIES'):    
     layer_info = ['(Key: %s, Value: %s)' % (key, layer.serviceProperties[key]) for key in layer.serviceProperties.keys()]
     print layer_info
```

Or to directly check for the URL you would do this:

```
if layer.supports('SERVICEPROPERTIES'):
    if 'URL' in layer.serviceProperties.keys():
        url = layer.serviceProperties['URL']
```

[See here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) for more details about the service properties dictionary, scroll down to the *Properties* section of the page.